# Using L298n motor driver without jumper (Voltage Regulator)

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, battery

When I am using 9V supply with motor driver and Jumper connected so the red LED was blinking but when I did the same using 9V and 15V supply removing the jumper LED didn't blink.
Neither the voltage nor the current drop across the motor was observed. And I didn't found any documentation for using L298n using without a jumper.
[image]

Comment: You need to provide a link to that specific driver board. The L298N is only the H-bridge chip on it. The circuit around it (including the jumpers and headers) is specific to that board. Please include that link in your question (by editing it)

Comment: The jumper controls whether or not the on-board 5V regulator is used to power the on-board logic. With the jumper removed the board needs an external 5V supply in addition to the motor power supply.

Comment: Is your Arduino ground connected to the 15V power supply ground?